# routing in angularjs like cakephp

Tags: cakephp, routes, angularjs

i am trying to implement routing in angularjs. But i wish to do it in a the same way as is done in cakephp.
for eg:
in cakephp if i pass something like

```
blog/manager/users/index/page:2/sort:username/direction:asc
```

or

```
blog/manager/users/index/sort:username/direction:asc/page:2
```

both generate the same result. i.e. cakephp understands the named parameters passed in the url in any order (order doesn't matter).
What if i need to do the same in angularjs?
For now i have following coding for my routing controller in angularjs:

```
    angular.module('productapp', []).
    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/productapp', {templateUrl: 'partials/productList.html', controller: productsCtrl}).
        when('/productapp/:productId', {templateUrl: 'partials/edit.html', controller: editCtrl}).
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/productapp'});
        }], 
        ['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode = true;
}]);
```

Do i need to hardcode each and every combination of the named parameter? or is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`when('/blog/manager/users/index/:param1/:param2/:param2, {templaeURL: 'mytmpl', controller: MyCtrl}).`

now param1,param2 and param3 can receive anything, but if you want to do something with the parameters you have to validate in your controller (eg: MyCtrl).

Comment: is this the only way to implement this? i mean isn't there a way by which i can do it without validating in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP (or any backend language), you can be that flexible with your URLs because of mod_rewrite and the `$_GET` object. In JavaScript, we have to add all of that extra logic that's given to us for free.

Using your example above with the blog URLs, here's how I'd write those in Angular:

```js
$routeProvider.
    when('blog/manager/users/index/:page/:sort/:direction', {
        controller: blogController
    }).
    when('blog/manager/users/index/:sort/:direction/:page', {
        controller: blogController
    });
```

If you wish not to create a route for each possible combination and order of parameters, I suggest looking into the `resolve` parameter or writing a custom params function that watches the routing events.